# Need help regarding Sprite Movements in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine, game-engine

I am developing a game in which I have one player moving on the screen by using on screen analog control.
Enemy sprites are getting added in the scene periodically and they move towards player. By using below code enemies are getting added.

```
public void addTarget() {
    Random rand = new Random();

    float x = ( camera.getWidth() + resourcesManager.evilone_region.getWidth());
    float minY = resourcesManager.evilone_region.getHeight();
    int maxY = (int) (camera.getHeight() - resourcesManager.evilone_region
        .getHeight());
    int rangeY = (int) (maxY - minY);
    float y = rand.nextInt(rangeY) + minY;

    target = new AnimatedSprite(x, y, resourcesManager.evilone_region.deepCopy(),vbom){
        @Override
        protected void preDraw(GLState pGLState, Camera pCamera) 
        {
           super.preDraw(pGLState, pCamera);
           pGLState.enableDither();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) 
        {
            super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
           if(isPlayerMoved){
               this.registerEntityModifier(new MoveModifier(2, target.getX(),player.getX(),target.getY(),player.getY()));
           }
        }

    };
    attachChild(target);

    target.setCullingEnabled(true);
    final long[] PLAYER_ANIMATE = new long[] {100, 100, 100};
    target.animate(PLAYER_ANIMATE, 0, 2, true);

    int minDuration = 2;
    int maxDuration = 4;
    int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
    int actualDuration = rand.nextInt(rangeDuration) + minDuration;

    mod = new MoveModifier(actualDuration, target.getX(),player.getX(),target.getY(),player.getY());

    target.registerEntityModifier(mod.deepCopy());
    TargetsToBeAdded.add(target);

}
private void createSpriteSpawnTimeHandler() {
    float mEffectSpawnDelay = 1f;

    eviloneTimerHandler = new TimerHandler(mEffectSpawnDelay, true,
    new ITimerCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
            if(isPaused){

            }else{
                //resourcesManager.targetbird.play();
                 addTarget();
            }

        }
    });

    engine.registerUpdateHandler(eviloneTimerHandler);
}
```

Now the problem is when I move the player with analog control I want result as every enemy should change the direction and move towards player. But by using this code every enemy is moving towards first added enemy and they all move towards player which looks very weird as all of them collapses on each other.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have directly move your enemies to player. You can move them 5 pixels every update or something like that. Here is an example but this code must be improved:

```
        @Override
        protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) 
        {
            super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);

            if( player.getX() > target.getX() )
            {
                 //Move your enemy 5 pixels to right
            }
            else
              //Move your enemy 5 pixels to left

            if( player.getY() > target.getY() )
            {
                 //Move your enemy 5 pixels to down
            }
            else
              //Move your enemy 5 pixels to up
        }
```

Note: Dont forget to check if target reached player. And before start moving your target check if it is currently moving. You can use a boolean to chechk it. Hope it helps.